# how to filter the first 4 objects of a model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I wanna get the first 4 Blog objects associated with the Blog Model.

I tried this:

```
#views
blog_list = blog.objects.all().order_by("id")[:4]
```

This works until I create more than 4 blog objects, and then the result doesn't include the recently created objects rather it gets stuck with the first 4 objects.

Comment: Well you always get the first four, since you get the `Blog` items with the smallesst primary key, which will be (approximately) the "oldest" four.

Comment: In other words, do you really want the "first 4" or the "latest 4"?

Comment: Damn, I was so worked up that I didn't even think to myself how it sounded or if it made any sense haha! sorry to bother thx tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always get the first four, since you get the `Blog` items with the smallest primary key, which will be (approximately) the "oldest" four.

You can order in *descending* order with:

```
blog_list = blog.objects.order_by('-id')[:4]
```

The primary key however does not *fully* guarantee that this is the order in which objects are created, and is thus *not* a safe way to do this.

You can also work with a "random order", although this is often computationally expensive:

```
blog_list = blog.objects.order_by('?')[:4]
```

or use the that is determined by the [**`ordering`** option <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering), or if there is no such option by the order that the database uses (which *can* be
any order):

```
blog_list = blog.objects.all()[:4]
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`blog`</s> to `Blog`.

Comment: I'd say the PK _might_ not guarantee it's in creation order, and the defaults for the usual RDBMSes used with Django do guarantee it.